# Python sklearn SVC.fit() got error

Tags: python, error-handling, scikit-learn, svm

My former version of sklearn is 0.13 and now I update it to 0.14.1. And my code below doesn't work now(It worked well before updating). Anyone know the reason? Here is my code and result.

```
print 'Reading train data...'
dataset=genfromtxt(open(r'Data/train.csv','r'),delimiter=',',dtype=int,skip_header=1)
train_data=[i[1:] for i in dataset]
label=[i[0] for i in dataset]

print 'Training...'
clf=svm.SVC(kernel='poly',degree=9)
clf.fit(train_data,label)

pickle.dump(clf,open(model,'w'))
```

And here is the result:

```
Reading train data...
Training...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svm_train.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "svm_train.py", line 23, in main
    clf.fit(train_data,label)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 178, in fit
    fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 233, in _dense_fit
    max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
  File "libsvm.pyx", line 53, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit (sklearn\svm\libsvm.c:1388)
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_seed'
```

Also, My python environment is anaconda python.

Comment: You probably botched the upgrade so you've now got a mixed 0.14.1/0.13 installation: the 0.13 Python code is trying to call into an 0.14.1 Cython/C module. Without seeing the upgrade command, it's hard to tell what went wrong, but try uninstalling 0.13.

Comment: the command is "conda update scikit-learn".

Comment: More generally, a polynomial kernel of degree 9 has to be questioned, and justified by significantly outperforming, say, degree 4 or 2 or 1 ...

Comment: @eickenberg Hadn't even seen that. It might be useful for approximating an exponential function...